# Not able to start a new Ionic4 project

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to start an Ionic 4 project from cmd and getting the following error
I tried to solve the problem by searching for solutions for the same type of errors and I could not find which one will solve my problem.
I tried to edit the etc/host file also to add the localhost port configurations as found in StackOverflow but no luck.

```
/ Downloading and extracting blank starter
[ERROR] Network connectivity error occurred, are you offline?
If you are behind a firewall and need to configure proxy settings, see: https://ion.link/cli-proxy-docs
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host host:80
```

Comment: From the command line can you access the web? Like try `ping microsoft.com` - does that work?

Comment: it's a network connectivity issue.

Comment: getting Request timed out. error by pinging microsoft.com

Comment: getting this error: silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular-devkit/build-angular@~0.13.0 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular-devkit%2fbuild-angular failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host host:80

Answer (score 0):

Today I solved the problem.
I found the mistake done in Environment Variables.
I removed the following values from Environment variable and now it is working fine.

```
user variables:
http://host:port
PROXY

system Variables:
http_proxy
http://username:password@host:port
```